The Instagram API responded with an error: Error #0
I installed the spotlight plugin in order to present my Instagram feeds on the Gallery page of my website ( https://elfofeliz.com/gallery ). Firstly I connected one of my Instagram account and it worked as expected, but then I decided to remove that account and connect another one, I did exactly the same steps as for the first one, but this time I got an error message:

The Instagram API responded with an error: Error #0 [Unknown]: Client error: GET https://graph.instagram.com/26522682874043499/media?access_token=Ge/oGI+XObzYBY8YqZvX1MvweXcDO6R7e6qrXpcWm/bsiRbKIFyPA2PHcwiRXa+dYrzzDMN+7/Yn3mq+d+MlxEiEFJAa/zTe7f2OR0V8H5u5nKyHH4/JbvK+uMTp2wTXO/EsgjUALU4ZebVGklREIiBxDpdMpE3WUCV9k3ju9BGGXBMQYCI7qJ8JVMKOriogiycZDsqSjmtMRPVCxK0+/2OAbAlDef2P0XuwD0d/q65+LIxaHMySMFAIuZdU39Y0V7F+5nFpOHsVVl9YAVKWXmScOBj5TnYkN0ErCul2r14475wFVbNz/raXc+pR9hdTJ8sFpgdHbL1REnJ7hzwWHLmPKzF8AmzYkR5pNR4w8Np9y+G6Npo8WUAVg%3D%3D&fields=id,username,timestamp,caption,media_type,media_url,permalink,children%7Bid,%20media_url,%20media_type,%20permalink,%20thumbnail_url%7D,thumbnail_url&limit=50 resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: Sorry, this content isn’t available right now

As far as I understand it says that there are no feeds in the account, but this is not right.
What am I missing here? Why does this plugin work for one account and doesn’t for another one (both of them are personal accounts)?

the problem can come from the plugin or from the api. in the 2 cases, you will have more help in contacting them as asking help here.
